# Can valgrind report a segmentation fault + coredump when there isn't?

Tags: c, openssl, valgrind

I am writing a program which use the library openssl. My program is functionnal, but when i try to execute it with valgrind, I have a segmentation fault. When I try to juste execute it (on the os), there is no problem, even when I use gdb.

I red my code many times and I don't see where the error is.

Is it possible that there are no mistakes in my code ? thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post some exemplary code, like proposed at [sscce.org](http://sscce.org)

Comment: The thing with [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (the most usual cause of crashes) is that they are just *undefined*, and therefore unpredictable and may sometimes work. If you build your program with debug-information then Valgrind will tell you the filename and the line-number in the source-file where bad things are happening. You should check that first.

Comment: Thanks ! I was reducing my code before to post it here (as Sebastian said), removing all parts of error managment and re-executing it to ensure the behaviour was the same. By doing that I found where was my problem !  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can valgrind report a segmentation fault + coredump when there isn't?

Not likely.

The problem is probably in you coder, and the additional instrumentation provided by Valgrind exposes the bug.

Valgrind should be telling you where the problem is. With OpenSSL, the trick is differentiating the "benign findings" from the "bad findings". That's not easy because some of the OpenSSL devs don't care about clearing the benign findings. So the benign findings mask the bad findings.

As Sebastian said, if you provide more information you will likely get better answers.

Comment: Thanks ! I was reducing my code before to post it here (as Sebastian said), removing all parts of error managment and re-executing it to ensure the behaviour was the same. By doing that I found where was my problem !  :)